# Excluir usuário firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Boa tarde, eu estou com dificuldades em resolver uma questão. Estou dentro de uma fragmente programando meu botão de excluir conta,porém não está dando resultado, não acontece nada quando eu clico nele, acho que tem algo arrado.Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

```
buttonExcluirConta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Certeza?");
        dialog.setMessage("Deletar");

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                firebaseUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Conta  Excluida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });



       // removeConta();


    }
});
```

---

No caso esse códido está dentro de um Fragment.java
Fica correto eu presentá-lo desta forma getActivity conforme baixo?

new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

Eu coloquei o dialog.show();

Só que o dialog ficou em vermelho...

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando e configurando um diálogo ao apertar do botão. Porém, falta você inserir o comando para **efetivamente mostrar o diálogo**. Por isso nada acontece, o diálogo é criado e configurado mas não é mostrado.

O método que deve ser chamado para mostrar um diálogo é:
**dialog.show();**

Assim, o correto seria:

```
buttonExcluirConta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle("Certeza?");
        dialog.setMessage("Deletar");

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                firebaseUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Conta  Excluida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });



       // removeConta();

    dialog.show();
    }
    //MOSTRAR O DIÁLOGO
    
});
```

Comment: O comando diálogo.show() deve ficar logo abaixo do comando diálogo.SetPositiveButton ... Se ele ficou marcado em vermelho é porque estava fora do escopo do método OnClick.